# ASP.NET Core 2.1 - Options pattern - accessing options doesn't return instance of the bound class

Tags: c#, configuration, asp.net-core-2.1

i'm trying to follow [this example from Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.1) to retrieve some configuration options from an appsettings.json file in my ASP.NET Core 2.1 application.

I've bound the class

```
public class MailServer
{
    public string Host { get; set; }
    public int Port { get; set; }
    public bool UseSSL { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string FromAddress { get; set; }
    public MailServer()
    {
    }
}
```

to the config in Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // .....
    services.Configure<MailServer>(Configuration.GetSection("MailServer"));
    // .....
    services.AddSingleton<IScheduledTask, ScheduledTask>();
}
```

In the startup i also added ScheduledTask as a singleton in order to access the context from that specific class - that's also where i want to access the options.

```
public interface IScheduledTask
{
    void MonitorCloudHosts();
}

public class ScheduledTask : IScheduledTask
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _ServiceProvider;
    private readonly MailServer _mailServer;

    // note here you ask to the injector for IServiceProvider
    public ScheduledTask(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IOptions<MailServer> optionsAccessor)
    {
        _ServiceProvider = serviceProvider;
        _mailServer = optionsAccessor.Value;
    }

    public void MonitorCloudHosts()
    {
        // Do some stuff
        var xyz = _mailServer.Host;
    }
}
```

this is my appsettings.json file:

```
  {
    "Logging": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "AllowedHosts": "*",
    "ConnectionStrings": {
      "CloudMonitorConnection": "Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=CloudMonitor;Integrated Security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;",
      "HangFireConnection": "Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=HangFire;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
    },
    "MailServer": {
      "Host": "smtp.gmail.com",
      "Port": "587",
      "UseSSL": "True",
      "Username": "xxxxxxx@gmail.com",
      "Password": "xxxxxxx",
      "FromAddress": "xxxxxxx<xxxxxxx@gmail.com>"
    }
  }
```

compiler gives error on calling _mailServer.Host saying "An object reference is required..." - but doesnt give error on `optionsAccessor.Value`.

Shouldn't `optionsAccessor.Value` return an instance of MailServer? Am I doing some rookie mistake here?

Comment: Code looks good. Maybe there's a problem in appsettings.json?

Comment: @PavelLevchuk added appsettings.json - thanks!

Comment: Change `UseSSL` property: `"UseSSL": true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Property `UseSSL` of `MailServer` class is `bool` but is set to `"True"` in appsettings.json.

You should change appsettings.json like this:

```
"MailServer": {
  "Host": "smtp.gmail.com",
  "Port": 587,
  "UseSSL": true,
  "Username": "xxxxxxx@gmail.com",
  "Password": "xxxxxxx",
  "FromAddress": "xxxxxxx<xxxxxxx@gmail.com>"
}
```

EDIT:
I have created an empty project with this code and it compiles. Maybe there's an error in using statement or strict mode is enabled?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

namespace samp
{
    public class MailServer
    {
        public string Host { get; set; }
        public int Port { get; set; }
        public bool UseSSL { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string FromAddress { get; set; }
        public MailServer()
        {
        }
    }

    public interface IScheduledTask
    {
        void MonitorCloudHosts();
    }

    public class ScheduledTask : IScheduledTask
    {
        private readonly IServiceProvider _ServiceProvider;
        private readonly MailServer _mailServer;

        // note here you ask to the injector for IServiceProvider
        public ScheduledTask(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IOptions<MailServer> optionsAccessor)
        {
            _ServiceProvider = serviceProvider;
            _mailServer = optionsAccessor.Value;
        }

        public void MonitorCloudHosts()
        {
            // Do some stuff
            var xyz = _mailServer.Host;
        }
    }

    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
            services.Configure<MailServer>(Configuration.GetSection("MailServer"));
            services.AddSingleton<IScheduledTask, ScheduledTask>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It still gives the same error - even setting that to true - i also changed the port which is int to be 587 instead of "587" - but still cannot compile :(

Comment: found the issue. I had the method in which the MailServer object was used down as static. Dropping the static and doing the change you said made it work - Thanks!